# PHP exec/passthru/system produces different result than executing manually from command line, why?

Tags: python, php, pdf, exec, passthru

I am currently trying to launch a print from localhost/php by doing an exec/passthru/system on a python script

php part:

```
<?php
passthru('C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe C:\gs\print.py', $output); 
?>
```

python part:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import win32print
import win32api
import requests

PDFXC = "C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe"

LOCAL_FILE = "C:/gs/label.pdf"
currentprinter = "BIXOLON SRP-770II"
url='https://www.myserver.com/mydata/label.pdf'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open(LOCAL_FILE, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
params = ' /printto "'+currentprinter+'" "'+LOCAL_FILE+'"'
print(params);
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', PDFXC, params, '.',0)
```

xampp / windows

And now to the weird part, executing the python script from **windows cmd ** everything prints as it should, executing it from PHP no matter if by **exec, passthru** or **system**. The print is missing parts or with a different document 3 empty pages are "printed" after each page.

WHY? Basically PHP shouldn't do anything else than me executing the python script manually from command line ?

- 

Comment: With full error reporting enabled, are there any errors or warnings? Have you inspected stdout and stderr? My guess is that you’ll find something about not being able to find a library/module because the user that PHP is running as via the web (which is different than you on the CLI) doesn’t have their PATH or include directories pointing to the correct location

Comment: No warnings / errors in php, I even removed the python part now and did the download/execution in php. However it works on Windows 11 but not on the old Windows 7 machine. Guess I'll just upgrade it then.